# Why would a Scala Worksheet using Scala-IDE give this as an error?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

In a Scala worksheet I can do this:

```
object Play {

 println("Playing a bit")                         //> Playing a bit

 case class X(a: Int = 1, x: List[X]){
 }

}
```

but I can't do this:

```
object Play {

 case class X(a: Int = 1, x: List[X]){
 }

}
```

In the latter it will complain after the case class that `; was expected but import found`

Comment: I'm guessing because Worksheet is very new and contains bugs...

Comment: Thanks Luigi, you are probably right.

Comment: Hi @LuigiPlinge, will you put your comment as answer please. This is not a problem with the latest nightly's so you are spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that is fixed in the latest nightly build of Scala IDE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767214/770361