# Classes in Worksheet in Scala-IDE cause error

Tags: scala, scala-ide

Just instantiating a class by typing the following into a Worksheet (note, Worksheet, created with File > New > Scala Worksheet, a `.sc` file, not a normal `.scala` file) and clicking Save causes a spurious error:

[image]

Mouseover:

[image]

"Multiple markers at this line
- illegal start of simple expression
- ';' expected but identifier found."

I doubt something as simple as this could have slipped through testing so maybe it's a configuration issue. I've tried it on 2 machines and get the same behaviour:

1) Windows 7 with Eclipse Helios

2) Windows XP with Eclipse Indigo - clean download from Typesafe website

Any ideas? Do other people get this on their setup?

Comment: @giladhoch thanks - what operating system are you using?

Comment: Works for me, too. I am using Win7 64Bit, JDK 1.6.0_31, Scala 2.9.3, Eclipse 3.7.2, Scala-IDE 2.1.0.nightly !

Comment: @Peter that's odd then. The error only appears for me me when I click Save - did you save it and it displayed the result?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Yes, I just created a new workspace with one scala project with only one file containing your `object WorkSheet`, saved, compiled and there is no error message.

Comment: After hitting save, I get only the ';' expected error (Win7 64bit, Indigo, Scala 2.9.3)

Comment: @Keith actually, me too now. Still, good to know it's not just me.

Comment: Try to add a space between the `class Foo` line and the `new Foo` line.

Comment: @pedrofurla that does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the Scala compiler, but the fix is not in the version shipped with the milestone release.

If you update to a nightly build of the Scala IDE, you should be able to use this code pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get the nightly build running. If I try to install it, I get a bunch of conflicting dependencies: http://pastebin.com/TL90ReEF. So I tried uninstalling the existing Scala IDE and now Eclipse won't boot at all (IllegalStateException).

Comment: It looks like a problem with the Typesafe IDE. We're [looking into it](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/typesafe_stack/tickets/68#/activity/ticket:68).

Answer (score 4):

During the Martin Odersky lectures on [Coursera](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/class/index) I noticed that he declares his classes outside the main object in his workbooks.

I hope this helps

```
object Worksheet {
  new Foo
}

class Foo
```

Comment: Yes, great course, just finished assignment 3... but an inner class is a 100% legitimate scala code, so I assume he is doing it for either scoping or to avoid the bug (p.s. I love the shaun the sheep / timmy time avatar)