# scala error : ';' expected but 'import' found

Tags: scala

When I add this class to a scala worksheet I receive the error :

';' expected but 'import' found.

```
object polynomials {

    class Poly(val terms: Map[Int , Double]) {
        def + (other: Poly) = new Poly(terms ++ other.terms)
    }

    val p1 = new Poly(Map(1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 4.0, 5 -> 6.2))

}
```

The class looks fine to me, is there something missing ?

Comment: you might want to show the code that contains the import...

Comment: @Kim Stebel im not importing anything, i think this might be a scala worksheet bug

Comment: So the worksheet is otherwise empty?

Comment: Then I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615964/why-would-a-scala-worksheet-using-scala-ide-give-this-as-an-error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a bug. A new version of the Worksheet was released a few days ago that fixes it, so go to Help > Check for updates, and the new version should be available for installation. I tried your code on Worksheet 0.1.2.v-2_09-201210230838-85b738a and it's fine.